# display data in SharePoint 2013 through ODBC

Tags: sharepoint-designer, database-connection

We are two students doing our internship (meaning we work with SharePoint 2013) in a company where they are already using SharePoint 2007, they want to implement what they have in SP2007 into SP2013. Basically they have a list of customers and have an overview per customer what files and what invoices they have.
We want to start displaying the customers only (and then expand if possible). 
the database they are using is a Progress database, they gave us the IP address and login credentials for the ODBC.
So my question is, how do we use this ODBC connection to display a list of all the customers in SharePoint 2013?
If you need additional information, feel free to ask.
Kind regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to either create a custom BDC connector to connect to Progress (either directly or via ODBC) or using some other data elements like a web part or ASPX page, connect directly to Progress. Using a BDC connector will allow you to treat the data like a SharePoint list, giving users a more consistent feel.

if they're doing it in 2007 already, can you investigate how? You might be able to use their setup as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

they are using a custom made tool, that person no longer works at thesame company and we simply don't have the knowledge to build/adapt the tool they made. Isn't there some kind of wizard to guide us through to connect through ODBC? I keep ending up having an error when I try to fill in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of connection strings out there on the internet for different datasources. Please, check out http://www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: can you elaborate in order to answer the question at hand?